# Created 3D object , but it doesn't rotate in cocos3d

Tags: cocos3d

I created one 3D object using **Blender 2.66** and **PowerVR Graphics SDK**. I added the pod file and   altered the hello-world project simply by replacing pod file name and node name.But the 3D object is not rotating. Is there any other changes tat i have to do in code? Is there any chance of error in pod file creation ? Thanks .

Comment: Please show us your specific code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you create a project in cocos3d the default pod file syntax is
[self addContentFromPODFile:@"hello-world.pod"]; 
you replace it with
where u use any node name

> withName:@"HelloText"

[self addContentFromPODFile:@"hello-world.pod" withName:@"**abc**"];

And where you fild cc3meshnode replace getnodenamed with you set above

CC3MeshNode* hellotext = (CC3MeshNode*)[self getNodeNamed:@**"abc"**];